# Perl DBI modifying Oracle database by creating a VIEW

Tags: sql, perl, oracle, dbi

I wrote a Perl script to check the data in an Oracle database. Because the query process is very complex I chose to create a VIEW in the middle. Using this view the code could be largely simplified.

The Perl code run well when I used it to query the database starting from a file, like `Perl mycode.pl file_a`. The Perl code reads lines from `file_a` and creates/updates the view until the end of the input. The results I achieved are completely right.

The problem came when I simultaneously run

```
perl mycode.pl file_a
```

and

```
perl mycode.pl file_b
```

to access the same database. According to my observation, the VIEW used by the first process will be modified by the second process. These two processes were intertwined on the same view.

Is there any suggestion to make these two processes not conflict with one another?

The Perl code for querying database is normally like this, but the details in each real query is more complex.

```
my ($gcsta,$gcsto,$cms) = @t; #(details of @t is read from a line in file a or b)

my $VIEWSS = 'CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW VIEWSS AS SELECT ID,GSTA,GSTO,GWTA FROM TABLEA   WHERE GSTA='.$gcsta.' AND GSTO='.$gcsto.' AND CMS='.$cms;

my $querying = q{ SELECT COUNT(*) FROM VIEWSS WHERE VIEWSS.ID=1};

my $inner_sth = $dbh->prepare($VIEWSS);
my $inner_rv  = $inner_sth->execute();

$inner_sth = $dbh->prepare($querying);
$inner_rv  = $inner_sth->execute();
```

Comment: Pls, post a code snippet. Also, i don't think that you should be creating (or replace) a view every time i.e. run a DDL every time.

Answer (score 1):

You must

- Create the view only once, and use it everywhere
- Use placeholders in your SQL statements, and pass the actual parameters with the call to `execute`

Is this the full extent of your SQL? Probably not, but if so it really is fairly simple.

Take a look at this refactoring for some ideas. Note that is uses a *here document* to express the SQL. The `END_SQL` marker for the end of the text must have no whitespace before or after it.

If your requirement is more complex than this then please describe it to us so that we can better help you

```
my $stmt = $dbh->prepare(<<'END_SQL');
SELECT count(*)
FROM tablea
WHERE gsta = ? AND gsto = ? AND cms= ? AND id = 1
END_SQL

my $rv = $stmt->execute($gcsta, $gcsto, $cms);
```

---

If you *must* use a view then you should use placeholders in the `CREATE VIEW` as before, and make every set of changes into a transaction so that other processes can't interfere. This involves disabling `AutoCommit` when you create the database handle `$dbh` and adding a call to `$dbh->commit` when all the steps are complete

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use DBI;

my $dbh = DBI->connect('dbi:Oracle:mydbase', 'user', 'pass',
        { AutoCommit => 0, RaiseError => 1 } );

my $make_view = $dbh->prepare(<<'END_SQL');
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW viewss AS
SELECT id, gsta, gsto, gwta
FROM tablea
WHERE gsta = ? AND gsto = ? AND cms= ? AND id = 1
END_SQL

my $get_count = $dbh->prepare(<<'END_SQL');
SELECT count(*)
FROM viewss
WHERE id = 1
END_SQL

while (<>) {

  my ($gcsta, $gcsto, $cms) = split;

  my $rv = $make_view->execute($gcsta, $gcsto, $cms);
  $rv = $get_count->execute;
  my ($count) = $get_count->fetchrow_array;
  $dbh->commit;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Several days ago I proposed the question about using execute() pass parameters to dynamically create views. I mentioned that it did not work for my case. And I turned to use some 'a'.$var.'b' to concatenate my directive. Finally it works. But I believe what you mentioned is a standard to do such a wok.

Comment: Then you may as well use the `do` method, which is `prepare` and `execute` combined

Answer (score 0):

Is the view going to be the same or different?

If the views are all the same then create it only once, or check if it exists with the all_views table :  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10755/statviews_1202.htm#i1593583

You can easily create a view including your pid with the $$ variable to be the pid, but it wont be unique across computers, oracle has also some unique ids, see http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10759/functions150.htm, for example, the SESSIONID.

But do you really need to do this? why dont you prepare a statement and then execute it? http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBI/DBI.pm#prepare

thanks,
mike

Comment: Thanks, mike. I'm a newbie. So the plan I used may be problematic. Your suggestion is very helpful. Before this, I'm considering to create a large random number to identify the view, but it still can't guarantee the view id will be unique.

Comment: SESSIONID should be what you want. But I think you should go with the prepared queries, not with views. The prepared query is basically like a temp view.

Comment: Since you are new, dont forget to vote up my responses if the help you!